# Buefy b-checkbox and VeeValidate

Tags: validation, vee-validate, buefy

I'm trying to make a required checkbox — i.e. checkbox must be checked — using [VeeValidate](https://baianat.github.io/vee-validate/) with [Buefy](https://buefy.github.io).

Much like [this example from the **VeeValidate docs**](https://baianat.github.io/vee-validate/examples/checkboxes.html#validating-checkboxes).

Is there any way to use `v-validate="'required'"`, or similar, on a single Buefy `<b-checkbox/>`?

Do I have to fall back to a vanilla `<input type="checkbox">` in this situation?

[**Buefy docs** have a page about using VeeValidate](https://buefy.github.io/extensions/veevalidate/) but checkboxes aren't covered.

Thanks

Comment: Try using the DOM inspector and seeing if anything like a checkbox was even created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [Buefy VeeValidate Extension documentation](https://buefy.github.io/extensions/veevalidate) now includes a required checkbox example.

Example added on request in [Buefy issue #1054](https://github.com/buefy/buefy/issues/1054)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how you can validate the checkbox using `VeeValidate` in Vue 2.

```html
<ValidationProvider :rules="{required:{allowFalse: false}}" v-slot="{ errors, valid }">
  <b-checkbox v-model="accepted" />
  <p>{{ errors }}</p>
</ValidationProvider>
```

Here, I added validation to accept `true` value only. This means It must be checked.